# Issue with Facebook SSO on iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, facebook

I have a problem implementing Facebook SSO (single sign on):
when you run my app and try to log on, facebook app is started, then when you press ok or cancel instead of going back to my app ANOTHER APP is being run (it's one of our older apps)

main app has fb_APP_ID in plist, when i debug url it opens
fbauth://authorize?type=user_agent&display=touch&redirect_url=fbconnect%3A%2F%2Fsuccess&sdk=ios&scope=offline_access&client_if=APP_ID
where APP_ID is of course number

the older app doesnt have fb_APP_ID in it's plist...

if I run hackbook sample code, it runs ok

Any ideas? Thank you!

Comment: Is this happened on Simulator and Device ? are you using unique Bundle ID for every app or you have a general one to test with it ? Did you try to delete the old app ?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Delete the old app and your current app and its will work fine.